# Find nth smallest element in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have written an algorithm for finding nth smallest element in BST but it returns root node instead of the nth smallest one. So if you input nodes in order 7 4 3 13 21 15, this algorithm after call find(root, 0) returns Node with value 7 instead of 3, and for call find(root, 1) it returns 13 instead of 4. Any thoughts ?

```
Binode* Tree::find(Binode* bn, int n) const
{
    if(bn != NULL)
    {

    find(bn->l, n);
    if(n-- == 0)
        return bn;    
    find(bn->r, n);

    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

and definition of Binode

```
class Binode
{
public:
    int n;
    Binode* l, *r;
    Binode(int x) : n(x), l(NULL), r(NULL) {}
};
```

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Your code does not make much sense semantically or algorithmically.

Comment: you don't use results of find(bn->l, n) and find(bn->r, n);

Comment: If you take `n` parameter by-reference instead of by-value and make some use of results of your recurrent calls to `find` it might work.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to efficiently retrieve the n-th smallest element in a binary search tree by itself. However, this does become possible if you keep in each node an integer indicating the number of nodes in its entire subtree. From [my generic AVL tree implementation](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/structure/BAVL.h):

```
static BAVLNode * BAVL_GetAt (const BAVL *o, uint64_t index)
{
    if (index >= BAVL_Count(o)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    BAVLNode *c = o->root;

    while (1) {
        ASSERT(c)
        ASSERT(index < c->count)

        uint64_t left_count = (c->link[0] ? c->link[0]->count : 0);

        if (index == left_count) {
            return c;
        }

        if (index < left_count) {
            c = c->link[0];
        } else {
            c = c->link[1];
            index -= left_count + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, `node->link[0]` and `node->link[1]` are the left and right child of `node`, and `node->count` is the number of nodes in the entire subtree of `node`.

The above algorithm has O(logn) time complexity, assuming the tree is balanced. Also, if you keep these counts, another operation becomes possible - given a pointer to a node, it is possible to efficiently determine its index (the inverse of the what you asked for). In the code I linked, this operation is called `BAVL_IndexOf()`.

Be aware that the node counts need to be updated as the tree is changed; this can be done with no (asymptotic) change in time complexity.

Comment: Thanks Ambroz, this works great, I have never considered that not recursive way would be much easier to do it :)

Comment: @lukas7674 the point here is the use of node counts, not recursion versus iteration. This algorithm can easily be expressed in a recursive way (though it will likely be slower).

Comment: Thanks again, I've just done it recursively and it does work ! So much to learn...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

1) `find()` returns a value (the correct node, assuming the function is working as intended), but you don't propagate that value up the call chain, so top-level calls don't know about the (possible) found element

.

```
Binode* elem = NULL;
elem = find(bn->l, n);
if (elem) return elem; 
if(n-- == 0) 
    return bn;     
elem = find(bn->r, n); 
return elem; // here we don't need to test: we need to return regardless of the result
```

2) even though you do the decrement of `n` at the right place, the change does not propagate upward in the call chain.  You need to pass the parameter by reference (note the `&` after `int` in the function signature), so the change is made on the original value, not on a copy of it

.

```
Binode* Tree::find(Binode* bn, int& n) const
```

I have not tested the suggested changes, but they should put you in the right direction for progress

Comment: Thanks Attila for your answer, I used solution proposed by Ambroz where I keep the size of the left subtree in every node. Having this additional information in every node makes it much easier to find the demanded node.

Comment: @lukas7674 - please accept Ambroz's answer if it helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

We can use iterative/recursive inorder search to get the nth smallest element as shown below:

```
void insert(Node*& root, int val) 
{
  if(!root) {
    Node* temp = new Node(val);
    root = temp;
    return ;
  }

  if(val < root->val)
    insert(root->left,val);
  else if (val > root->val)
    insert(root->right, val);

}

// Utility function to print inorder traversal
void inorder_iterative(Node* root)  //iterative
{
        Node* temp = root;
        stack<Node*> st;
        int n = 0;
        while (temp != NULL || !st.empty()) {
                if (temp != NULL) {
                        st.push(temp);
                        temp = temp->left;
                }
                else {
                        temp = st.top();
                        st.pop();
                        cout << n++ << ":" << temp->val << " ";
                        temp = temp->right;
                }
        }
}

void inorder_recursive(Node* root) //recursive
{
  static int n ;
  if(!root)
    return;

  inorder_recursive(root->left);
  cout << n++ << ":" << root->val << " ";
  inorder_recursive(root->right);
}

 

// Driver code
int main()
{
        Node* root = NULL;
        insert(root, 30);
        insert(root, 50);
        insert(root, 15);
        insert(root, 20);
        insert(root, 10);
        insert(root, 40);
        insert(root, 60);

        // Function call to print the inorder traversal
        inorder_recursive(root);
        inorder_iterative(root);

        return 0;
}
```

Output: 0:10 1:15 2:20 3:30 4:40 5:50 6:60